# Pause in SpriteKit game

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

```
func pause() {
    pausedSpeed = self.speed
    self.speed = 0
    backgroundMusicPlayer.pause()
    worldNode.alpha = 0.7

    resumeButton = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 50))
    resumeButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2 - 50)
    resumeButton.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 50))
    resumeButton.name = resumeButtonName

    pauseLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "PAUSED")
    pauseLabel.fontSize = 100
    pauseLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2 + 100)
    pauseLabel.fontColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    worldNode.addChild(resumeButton)
    worldNode.addChild(pauseLabel)
}
```

Even thought I set self.speed to 0, a node still keeps moving. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: make your SKView pause by set `view.paused = true`

Comment: It does pauses the game. But now it doesn't add the label and the button. How do I do stuff after pausing the game?

Comment: The resume button works, but it doesn't show the nodes.

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not change the speed of the node. Just change `node.paused = true`

In your case, you should define all your control buttons on one `SKNode`, and declare all the game elements on another `SKNode`. In that case, if you want to pause the game, just make the second `SKNode` pause.